# Quandl Error in R

Tags: error

Please Help

I am trying to download data from Quandl using R but getting following
error, request you to look into and please help me out.

data[[i]] = Quandl(tick , start_date = Prev_day_dt , end_date = Today_dt)*
*Error:* 
              

*Attention Required! | Cloudflare*







*

I was able to download data since last week but after last Friday I stuck
with above error.

Comment: seems to be a reproducable error: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Need-Help-in-Quandl-Getting-Error-in-R-td4749218.html

Comment: another question with some additional info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179749/error-when-displaying-a-link-preview-attention-required-cloudflare